# How can I make a code of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm working on a JS library which gets images as code. Please take a look at it:

[image]

As you know, those selected strings are a long string which make images. Each of them is an image. I mean if you put that long-string as the value of `src` in `<img>` tag, then an image will be appeared as an image.

Anyway, I want an image and I need to make it code. How can I do that? Any specific tool?

Comment: May i suggest that you use Php to convert Mysql data to JSON? in mysql you just have to type the image file path.

Comment: Thats called *base64*, google it and you find many converters...

Comment: @JonasW. I did it, and I found some online converter. thank you. Also I'm wonder why IDEs doesn't have such a tool. An IDE like PHPStorm should add that feature `;-)`